# Using AJAX to return JSON from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Apologies if this is a repeat question, but any answer I have found on here hasn't worked me. I am trying to create a simple login feature for a website which uses an AJAX call to PHP which should return JSON. I have the following PHP:

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $numrows=0;
 $password=$_POST['password'];
 $username=$_POST['username'];
 $query="select fname, lname, memcat from members where (password='$password' && username='$username')";
 $link = mysql_query($query);
 if (!$link) {
  echo 3;
  die();
 }
 $numrows=mysql_num_rows($link);
 if ($numrows>0){  // authentication is successfull
   $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)) {
    $json[] = $r;
   }

   echo json_encode($json);  
  } else {
  echo 3;  // authentication was unsuccessfull
 }
?>
```

AJAX call:

```
$( ".LogIn" ).live("click", function(){
    console.log("LogIn button clicked.")
    var username=$("#username").val();
    var password=$("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;

         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "scripts/sendLogDetails.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function(data){
              if (data == '3') {
             alert("Invalid log in details - please try again.");
             }

              else {
             sessionStorage['username']=$('#username').val();
             sessionStorage['user'] = data.fname + " " + data.lname;
             sessionStorage['memcat'] = data.memcat;
             storage=sessionStorage.user;
             alert(data.fname);
             window.location="/awt-cw1/index.html";
             }
            }
           });
}
```

As I say, whenever I run this the values from "data" are undefined. Any idea where I have gone wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: this code is terrifyingly insecure.

Comment: Can you post the output of echo json_encode($json); statement? I typically do this by going to the network pane of your inspect element in your browser. @AliMasudianPour Can you provide some suggestions that he should read up on if he would like to secure his code?

Comment: It's proof of concept nothing more

Comment: Better check your response in firebug or something. "3" is not valid json, perhaps use `json_encode(array('error' => 3));` then check `if (data.error && data.error == 3) {`. Also for your successful ones, you're creating an array so you'd need to do `data[0].fname` I think, or loop through them in the js

Comment: Define empty array $json = array(); before while loop should solve your data undefined issue.

Comment: Output of json on Network is: "2" and no properties - http://imgur.com/F1Kl8Vp